# dropbox embedded image for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, dropbox, dropbox-api

I use free DropBox account and have a WordPress website.
Required to storing images on the DropBox and embedded to my website.
So what I did:
  link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qg6u87tbit8v3z/mobile%20ninja.gif?dl=0
  I post this - `<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qg6u87tbit8v3z/mobile%20ninja.gif?dl=0" alt="" />`

It doesn't work. How to solve it?

Thanks for your collaboration.

Comment: <img src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8qg6u87tbit8v3z/mobile%20ninja.gif?dl=0" alt="" /> 

Just need to replace https://www.dropbox.com to http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8qg6u87tbit8v3z/mobile%20ninja.gif?dl=0" alt="" />
```

Just need to replace https://www.dropbox.com to http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com